# Unable to run GWT in dev mode. No declaration can be found for element 'aop:scoped-proxy'?

Tags: spring, gwt

GWT, Spring, Maven, and Eclipse are not playing nicely. I'm trying to run (a rather large) project on my local machine in development mode. I'm able to build the application successfully but I'm unable to run it in Eclipse. Production mode works when running in it from command line using `mvn gwt:run`.

I've narrowed it down to a problem with an xsd schema. It's unable to resolve `<aop:scoped-proxy />` in my context.xml file.

I'm using GWT 2.5, Spring 3.0.5-RELEASE and Maven 3.0.4. I've explicitly added spring-aop-3.0.5-RELEASE.jar to my classpath but still no luck.

#### Top of appContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd "
       default-init-method="init" default-lazy-init="true">
```

#### STDOUT

```
Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: 
Line 131 in XML document from class path resource [appContext.xml] is invalid; 
nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: 
The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 
'aop:scoped-proxy'.:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is 
strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'aop:scoped-proxy'.
```

#### Log File

```
[main] WARN factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Ignored XML validation warning
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 
'http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd', because 1) could 
not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of 
the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

Comment: Are you following [those instructions](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq#gwt_with_maven) for launching your project? (BTW, `mvn gwt:run` is DevMode, not prod mode)

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your response. I should clarify I got `mvn gwt:run` to work after moving `target/<appName>-<version>` to www but I'm thinking this is incorrect. I have Eclipse setup with `-war target/<appName>-<version>` in the GWT run params.

Comment: If I don't copy `target/<appName>-<version>` to www and I run `mvn gwt:run` I get the following error in browser "GWT module 'client' may need to be recompiled."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it running in development mode using `mvn gwt:run`. I was close the first time I ran into the problem.

One thing I was not aware of is the importance of `?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997` at the end of the URL. Without this GWT DevMode util would not be able to keep track of the users interaction.

`http://localhost:8888/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`

For safe measure I cleaned and rebuilt the maven project in Eclipse. Not sure if that had an affect on it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is (as mentioned in Log file) with:
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
Please try: 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd